# How do I simplify the circuit using source transformations to get the Thevenin equivalent?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, homework

[image]

I don't know what to do with the 17 Ω and 9 Ω. Can someone help me?

Comment: Dont you know nodal and mesh analysis?Why do you necessarily have to transform the sources?

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I simplify the circuit using source transformations to get the
> thevenin equivalent*

You start by using your eyes and what you know about voltage sources.

**Hint** - You need to look at the picture and make a fairly obvious simplification: -

[image]

I'm not going to solve it for you <-- this is just a **hint** to help you.